# What does height of an algebraic equation mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I want to solve this question but I don't understand what "height" of an algebraic equation is:

> Find the number of solutions of the set of all algebraic equations of height 2.

Comment: Where did the question come from?  If from a text, there should be a definition.  And what set do the variables and constants in your equation come from?  If it is $\mathbb{R}$, even linear equations have continuum many solutions.

Comment: Googling "height of an algebraic equation" finds a few references to a definition by Cantor:  the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients plus the degree minus 1. There's also [height of a polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_of_a_polynomial), which is similar but different.

Comment: @lhf's suggestion fits well with the question here. This definition is commonly part of an argument that there are countably many algebraic numbers.

Comment: Agree with Henning. For the purposes of enumerating algebraic numbers it is essential that there are only finitely many algebraic equations of a given height. The height of a polynomial fails in that score even though it is useful in other contexts.

Comment: how is the height of a multivariate algebraic equation defined? any references?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, page 43, problem 2, the sum of the absolute values given there is called the height of an algebraic equation.